# How to set authorization header in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am working on node application in which I am working on jsonwebtokens,passport-jwt.I created application backend side and working fine on postman but I stuck on front end side. when i send token in headers in postman then token based page open on postman fine but on front side display unauthorized.How can i send token in header so that this page also open on front end side.
My code:

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  if(req.body.name && req.body.password){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var password = req.body.password;
  }

  var user = users[_.findIndex(users, {name: name})];
  if( ! user ){
    res.status(401).json({message:"no such user found"});
  }

  if(user.password === req.body.password) {
    // from now on we'll identify the user by the id and the id is the only personalized value that goes into our token
    var payload = {id: user.id};
    var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
    //res.json({message: "ok", token: token});
   res.redirect('/secret')
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({message:"passwords did not match"});
  }
});

app.get("/secret", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res){
    res.json("Success! You can not see this without a token");

  });
```

Where am i doing wrong??

Comment: so you want to keep the authorized persistence after successful login

Comment: you can store your token in cookies than use the

Comment: @Rajaji yes It  can be used to validate future requests..

Answer (score 1):

in your */login* you can save them tokens in a sessionStorage for future use...

something like this

```
 if(user.password === req.body.password) {
  ....
        var payload = {id: user.id};
        var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
        req.session.token = token ;
    }

}
```

use this session to update sessionStorage on client side

[here is an article](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) that is what you need for keeping logged in post login...

also  you need to destroy the cookies on *Logout*

Comment: its for angular js..What is for normal javascript??

Comment: i have updated the answer...you need to pass this token to client side... keep them in a session ...send them to client side as an ajax response ...or in ejs.save it there..and you will authorised until logout

Comment: still not working..what will be part for app.get("/secret", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res){
    res.json("Success! You can not see this without a token");

  });
??

Comment: wait ...let me simulate the jwt thing on my side and get full code ..i will be back ... but the short answer for your question is *store in cookies*

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a token, you can send it as:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token 
});
```

Comment: Where did this I apply??

Comment: this should be applied where you are making your http request on frontside

Comment: var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token });
    return this._http.post(URL,DATA, {headers: headers}).map(
      (res: Response) => res.json( ));